# Understanding Scopes in Spooky JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs, spookyjs

This implementation of SpookyJS is really spooky. While using Gulp to run Mocha + SpookyJS tests, I am unable to see most console log output. I have been following the Quickstart steps on SpookyJS's github [page](https://github.com/SpookyJS/SpookyJS). Why can't I see these console log outputs?

```
describe('test', function () {
it('test 1', function(done){

    try {
        var Spooky = require('spooky');
    } catch (e) {
        var Spooky = require('../lib/spooky');
    }
    var spooky = new Spooky({
            child: {
                transport: 'http'
            },
            casper: {
                logLevel: 'debug',
                verbose: true
            }
        }, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                e = new Error('Failed to initialize SpookyJS');
                e.details = err;
                throw e;
            }

            spooky.start(URL);
            console.log('Hello 3');  //currently this is not printing anything to the console
            spooky.then(function () {                
                 this.emit('hello', 'Hello, from ' + this.evaluate(function () {
                 return document.title;
                 }));                  
            });
            spooky.run();
            console.log('Hello 1');  //currently this is not printing anything to the console
        });
        spooky.on('hello', function (line) {
           console.log(line);
        });
        spooky.on('console', function (line) {
           console.log(line);
        });
        spooky.on('error', function (e, stack) {
            console.error(e);

            if (stack) {
                console.log(stack);
            }
        });

    console.log('Hello 2');  //this is printing to the console
    done();

    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure your code reaches the point of logging? e.g. does the anonymous function run?

Comment: No, I don't see the doc title. The only console outputs currently are the Mocha progress bar and the Hello 2 console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying your code, it roughly looks like this:

```
describe('test', function () {
    it('test 1', function(done){
        var Spooky = require('spooky');
        var spooky = create a spooky object with a lot of logic in it;

        console.log('Hello 2');  //this is printing to the console
        done();
    });
});
```

The `spooky` object is created, and after that, the program flow simply continues. Anything that the `spooky` object does, it does asynchronously, later on.

After creating the `spooky` object, you get your `Hello 2` and then `done()` is called, which ends this test.

So, before any `hello` stuff can be processed, your tests ends already.

What might help is to move the `done()` line here:

```
spooky.on('hello', function (line) {
    console.log(line);
    done();
});
```

Then your test will end once the `hello` event has been caught.

Since I'm not familiar with `Spooky` or with what exactly you want to test, I'm afraid I can't be of any more help. Hopefully this gets you a step further.